# Dynamically iterating over EF entites

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, reflection, entity-framework-5

I have code like this:

```
public static void ImportData()
{
    string[] entites = new string[] 
    { 
        "Entity1",
        "Entity2",
        "Entity3"
    };

    using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        foreach (var entity in entites)
        {
            // the next two lines don't compile,
            // i'm just including them to show my intentions
            List<string> cols = typeof(entity).GetProperties().Select(a => a.Name).ToList();
            List<entity> rows = db.entity.ToList();

            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                foreach (var col in cols)
                {
                    // do stuff

                    var propertyInfo = row.GetType().GetProperty(col);
                    var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

                    if (propertyType == typeof(double?))
                    {
                        var val = (double?)row.GetType().GetProperty(col).GetValue(row);
                        // do stuff
                    }
                    else if (propertyType == typeof(decimal?))
                    {
                        var val = (decimal?)row.GetType().GetProperty(col).GetValue(row);
                        // do stuff
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is with `entities` - ie. the code above works if I actually use 'Entity1' etc. instead of looping through all my entites. How do I get the `cols` and `rows` collections to be generic collections that I can iterate over?

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what doesn't work when you use `Entity1` or supply the other snippet that does work, but which you can't make dynamic. I think I guessed your issue, hence my provided solution.

Comment: You should also be aware that the Entity Framework will create *dynamic proxies* which will not be of the same type as your actual entities but instead inherit from them. This could be relevant when you use reflection on entities and especially on their navigation properties. See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `typeof` with a strign parameter, buttypeof is a compile time construct, so you can't use it in this way.

Instead you can use [`Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You will need to pass the full namespace and type name, so `Entity1` will probably not work, it will probably expect something along the lines of `MyApplication.Entities.Entity`.

If you want to load the entities completely dynamically, you can also use `Assembly.Load` to load the assembly containing your entities into memory and then use `Assembly.GetType` to load the type itself.

Remember that an Entity can also have properties that are not mapped to a database column, this is the case when someone used a partial class to extend a generated class or used Entity Framework Code First to write the class by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't tested this, but assuming it works, what would I do about 'rows'? Ie. if I'm looping through the entities' full namespace strings, how do I get a List of all the rows from the db? If I'm not making sense and you still care enough to offer a solution I'll edit my question with a bit more info

Comment: You could call into objectContext.CreateObjectSet using Reflection to dynamically create the list container, then call Execute on the ObjectSet to fetch all values from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this post. But since there was no marking of "solved" here -  I created my own question: [EF get list of records in runtime from Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494050/) ...
I just got an answer that is simple and just what I needed. I was thinking if it also could solve this issue?
It is this simple line @Matt gave as an answer on my [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494050/) that gives you some opportunities:

```
dbContextInstance.Set(type)
```